# Clicked menu item in nav div displays in main div

Tags: html, html-lists

Have spent hours searching for what must be very simple.
To keep it simple let's just have 2 divs on a page, nav div and main div.
In a nav div, user clicks on a menu choice.

```
<li><a href="#"></a></li>
```

The clicked menu item is to display in main div.  I can take it on from there.

I use Dreamweaver 2017, have downloaded latest jQuery and Bootstrap. 
Am not too stupid, but must a wicked blind spot.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use jQuery like this:

HTML:

```
<a id="target1">
  Target 1
</a>
<a id="target2">
  Target 2 
</a>
<div style="height:100px; width:100px" class="other">
    Some Text
</div>
```

JS:

```
$( "#target1" ).click(function() {
  $('div.other').text('Target 1');
});

$( "#target2" ).click(function() {
  $('div.other').text('Target 2');    
});
```

Here is a CodePen:
https://codepen.io/Wall05/pen/wqxegZ

Comment: If you would relate (fill in) the JS and HTML specifically, I would be set for life with my site.